# Eventlog Generated Time Format - Millisecond

Tags: c#, datetime, event-log, milliseconds, custom-eventlog

i created an eventlog entry:

```
if (!EventLog.SourceExists("testeventlog"))
            EventLog.CreateEventSource("testeventlog","testeventlog");

EventLog.WriteEntry("testeventlog", "testevent");
```

After this i tried to read out the time generated:

```
eLog = new EventLog("testeventlog");
foreach (EventLogEntry entry in eLog.Entries)
{

     entry.TimeGenerated.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt");

}
```

My Problem is that the Milliseconds are 0 every time.
Is there any possibility to write an eventlogentry in which the milliseconds are saved, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EventLog does not store time at millisecond resolution. Generally, it should not be needed, because you should not write to it so often. If you need a log with higher resolution and custom messages, consider using a framework like NLog or Log4Net and writing messages to a file or db.